# How to retrive this data from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[image]

how can i retrieve all hospitalNames from Hospitals where all userIds are unknown.

Comment: Run a loop in `Hospitals` node. Then for every child, get hospitalName from that child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("medicine/Hospitals");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        hospitalArrayList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Hospital hospital = item.getValue(Hospital.class);
            hospitalArrayList.add(hospital);
            System.out.println(hospital);
        }
        dataRetrieved();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

```
private void dataRetrieved() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hospital.java simple example

```
public class Hospital {
    public HospitalData hospitalData;

    public Hospital(HospitalData hospitalData) { }

    public Hospital() { }

    public static class HospitalData {
        public String hospitalName;
        public String hospitalAddress;

        public HospitalData(String hospitalName, String hospitalAddress) { }

        public HospitalData() { }

    }

}
```

You can use this in adapter like this.

```
String name = hospitalArrayList.get(position).hospitalData.hospitalName;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to navigate the `DataSnapshot` that you get in `onDataChange`.

1. If you know the name of a child node in a snapshot, you can use `snapshot.child("hospitalData")` to get *that* child snapshot from its parent.
2. If you don't know the name of the children in a snapshot, you can loop over `snapshot.getChildren()` to access each child snapshot.

By combining these, you can navigate any structure.

So you'll want to loop over the users with `getChildren()`, then access `child("hospitalData")` of each user, and get the values of each individual property with something like `child("hospitalName").getValue(String.class)`.

Comment: i want to extract all hospitalNames and display them in recyclerview

Comment: I understood that from your question. My answer explains how to do that. If you're having a hard time implementing it, I recommend showing us what you tried already.

Comment: i have used this and got both hospitalsData and faculty databaseReference.orderByChild("hospitalData").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(). fetched results are not matching with the POJO class like this. If it would have fetched hospitalsData only, it would have worked.

Comment: for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            
                            System.out.println("Something  " + ds.getValue());
                        }
Results: all 8 like {hospitalData={hospitalEmail=shifa@gmail.com, hospitalNumber=03335992454, hospitalAddress=asdfg hjkl, hospitalName=shifa international}, faculty={azim ur rehman1={fees=Rs. 10000000, education=diploma, name=azim ur rehman, specialization=lifts, id=1}, saad ahmad siddiqui132={.................}}}

Comment: but when i use 
for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            
                            System.out.println("Something  " + ds.getValue(POJO.class));
                        }
it shows like 
pojo class path @614045

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your structure.
Make a new Node name hospital and put userId in each hospital object
i.e

```
- medicine
    ..........
 - medicineData
     ..........
 - Patients
   ..........
 - Pharmacies
   ..........
 - hospitals
   ..........
```