# Firebase RealTime Database: How iterate each key value

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase RealTime JSON Database Structure is look like

[image: RealTime JSON Database file]

First i want to iterate different company names from the Company Profile like, [Demo Company, Demo Company Two, Demo Company Three]
after i getting this then i want to get sub items of this list now this time Company name is child reference object, this second list is look like [Circuit 1, Circuit 2, ...]. Now once again I want to go deep and now this time Circuit names is child reference object and now I want package name list Example (0603, ...), like so on.

In short First I want parent name and then sub parent name and so on, and at the last i want Key value pairs and all Parents names also.

I tried code sample look like

```
TextView tvTestDelete = findViewById(R.id.tv_test_delete);
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Company Profile");
    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            Map<String, Object> testDeleteItem = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
            String temp = "";
            for(DataSnapshot i : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                temp += i.getKey() + ", ";
            }
            tvTestDelete.setText(temp);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {}
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {}
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
    };
    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
```

I am beginner in android and firebase connectivity and how its work. I really sorry for my bad English explanation, if you didn't understand my question please ask me which part, I will try to explain it. Please help me.

I will really Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which part of your code doesn't work the way you expect it to work? So: when you step through your `onChildAdded` in a debugger, what does it do? And what did you expect it to do? I also recommend reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66832359/how-to-retrive-this-data-from-firebase/66832471#66832471

Comment: for(DataSnapshot i : snapshot.getChildren()) {temp += i.getKey() + ", ";} In this code line I would expect all children names like, [Demo Company, Demo Company Two, Demo Company Three], would appear But I am getting only one name [Demo Company Two] only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're using `addChildEventListener`, your `onChildAdded` is getting called with the child nodes of `/Company Profile`. So your `onChildAdded` gets called for once each child with a snapshot of that child: `Demo Company`, `Demo Company Three`, `Demo Company Two`.

Inside `onChildAdded` you then loop over the child nodes of each of those, so at that point you go an extra level down into the JSON, and end up calling  `i.getKey()` on nodes like `Demo Company/Demo Circuit 1`, `Demo Company/Demo Circuit 2`, and later also on `Demo Company Three/Demo Circuit 1`, etc.

If you only want log the keys of the direct child nodes, those are available as `snapshot.getKey()` in your current code.

Alternatively you can `addValueEventListener`, in which case your `onDataChange` gets called with a snapshot of all of `/Company Profile`, and in that case you'd loop over `getChildren()` as you do now to get to the child nodes you're looing for.